# How can you create a vim mapping with a description

Tags: key-bindings, spacevim

**Context:**

I am using NeoVim on mac with a plugin called SpaceVim that I really like. SpaceVim basically loads a ton of mappings all mapped to the space bar.

I also have added a ton of my own personal mappings, all mapped to the comma key.

**Problem**

When I use SpaceVim mappings, there is a description for each option. For example, if I press "[SPC]f" (this is the SpaceVim mapping for all maps related to files), it will show me a list of options and a description for each option. See photo below:

[image]

When I use my own mappings, Vim will show all the options, but I am not sure how to create descriptions for each option. For example, if I press ",m" (this is will show all of my "Miscellaneous" mappings), there is no description:
[image]

**Question**

Does anyone know how to add these descriptions to custom vim mappings (stored in vimrc file)?

**UPDATE**
To clarify - I am trying to create mapping previews without the use of spacevim or any other plugin. I did find this plugin which looks promising, but still looking for simple a vim / neovim only solution (which may not exist).
https://github.com/spinks/vim-leader-guide
Also, custom mappings can be created via spacevim with custom previews (see here for docs - https://spacevim.org/documentation/#bootstrap-functions) but still hoping to find a vim / neovim only solution :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. Please check the documentation before posting a question. Here's a freebie for a new contributor: https://spacevim.org/documentation/#mappings-guide (Took me five minutes to find this despite never having used SpaceVim.)

Comment: @ClarkTaylor Once you find out from the docs, feel free to post a self answer with the steps that worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: @BLayer - sorry, to clarify, I am asking if this can be done easily without spacevim (purely in vim or neovim). I found this plugin which looks promising, but still sort of defeats the purpose of trying to do this purely in vim / neovim https://github.com/spinks/vim-leader-guide

Comment: That's a feature of SpaceVim. Native Vim has nothing of the sort. You'd have to code it up...which would be a waste of time, obviously, with a plugin(s) already doing it for you.

Comment: Thanks B and Ben! That makes sense. @D.BenKnoble, very nice! I will have to check out your plugin! Looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: As filbranden said, whatever you come up with that works for you, post an answer! I might just convert my comment to an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @BLayer said in the comments is correct; I thought SpaceVim used a plugin for this, but now I believe they have custom code. You can write your own code to do it (which is what you need to do in a "pure vim" solution), but at that point (unless a plugin doesn't offer what you need), it's not any different from using one.

Shameless plug: I use my own https://github.com/benknoble/popsikey plugin for this. It creates regular mappings when popups aren't supported, though it uses some newer vim8 syntax. It doesn't quite support every `map` feature, as that's a task with diminishing returns in this declarative style.

Here's a screenshot, for fun:

[image]

It's actually surprisingly versatile, especially with the submenu support. Here are a few examples:

- [define a popup mapping](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/12d754d10ef10eeee9411f360f8df9e7bf7122c4/links/vim/plugin/leader.vim#L11) and [add to it later](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/4aea55804683a90a0a79175b6fe1e2d9172ec092/links/vim/after/plugin/config/abolish.vim#L5)
- [include a submenu](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/12d754d10ef10eeee9411f360f8df9e7bf7122c4/links/vim/plugin/leader.vim#L62): with these, it's helpful to [define the submenu first](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/12d754d10ef10eeee9411f360f8df9e7bf7122c4/links/vim/plugin/leader.vim#L42) and then [unmap the menu prefix](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/12d754d10ef10eeee9411f360f8df9e7bf7122c4/links/vim/plugin/leader.vim#L52)
- [here's the search menu](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/12d754d10ef10eeee9411f360f8df9e7bf7122c4/links/vim/plugin/leader.vim#L74) from the screenshot